# How to fix TLS error in Azure Function App

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I have a functions app written in Powershell that worked up until a month or so ago.

The function uses a module (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NTware.Ufo.PowerShell.ObjectManagement/2022.2.0.1) that is only compatible with "Widows Powershell".

The module is loaded as follows:

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\Modules\NTware.Ufo.PowerShell.ObjectManagement.dll -UseWindowsPowerShell
```

The module allows connection to an external Azure environment that hosts an application.

The error returned is:

> 2022-09-02T13:38:31Z   [Warning]   WARNING: Module NTware.Ufo.PowerShell.ObjectManagement is loaded in Windows PowerShell using WinPSCompatSession remoting session; please note that all input and output of commands from this module will be deserialized objects. If you want to load this module into PowerShell Core please use 'Import-Module -SkipEditionCheck' syntax.
> 2022-09-02T13:38:34Z   [Error]   ERROR: Failed to authenticate.
> OriginInfo            : localhost
> Exception             :
> Type                           : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
> SerializedRemoteException      : System.ArgumentException: Failed to authenticate. ---> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: AADSTS1002016: You are using TLS version 1.0, 1.1 and/or 3DES cipher which are deprecated to improve the security posture of Azure AD

I have tried the following without success:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\Modules\NTware.Ufo.PowerShell.ObjectManagement.dll -UseWindowsPowerShell
```

I suspect the issue is that the remote Azure environment has started enforcing TLS 1.2. I have set my Azure Function App to also use TLS 1.2.

Any ideas on where the issue might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules imported with the `-UseWindowsPowerShell` are in fact loaded to a separate Windows PowerShell session in a separate process (see [about Windows PowerShell Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_windows_powershell_compatibility)). Changing the `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` variable in the local process does not affect other processes. You need to update this variable in the *remote* process, here is how:

```
$session = Get-PSSession -Name WinPSCompatSession

Invoke-Command -Session $session -Command {
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
}
```